# Is it possible to use Google's display ad platform to only display ads on a particular page of a particular site?

Tags: google-adsense

Using Google's display ad platform (ad sense), is it possible to only display ads on a particular page of a particular site, as long as that particular page is already serving ads through Google's display ad platform.

EG. Could i configure the ad to only be served on the page `example.com/pageone` but no other pages.

Comment: I think you are speaking about Google Ads (previously adwords) that advertisers use and not adsense that publishers use.  If so, you can add the specific URL in placements target.

Answer (score 1):

Ads are served only on pages that have `<script src=".../adsbygoogle.js">` tag. So if you have access to page rendering - you can add logic to add `adsbygoogle.js` script only to pages that you want to serve ads on.

AdSese Auto Ads allow you to exclude certain pages from serving ads [help article](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9262311?hl=en) but it's not what you want. As you want only a particular page to serve ads, which is opposite and I don't think you can achieve what you want using the exclusion feature.